# pandas to_datetime vs datetime fromtimestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following code which implies that `fromtimestamp` and `to_datetime` works differently:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

pd.to_datetime(1488286965000,unit='ms')
>>> Timestamp('2017-02-28 13:02:45')
datetime.fromtimestamp(1488286965000/1e3)
>>> datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 1, 0, 2, 45)
```

When I go to https://www.epochconverter.com/ it seems that the pandas version is correct.

1. Is there a reason that the `datetime` version is giving a different answer?
2. Also is this possibly a bug?

Comment: It's merely using a different timezone. Try `datetime.fromtimestamp(1488286965000/1e3, tz=timezone.utc)`…

Comment: Are you located in the GMT+11 timezone? :) `to_datetime` and `fromtimestamp` have a different default timezone. You need to specify UTC in the `fromtimestamp`.

Comment: @deceze do you want to leave that as an answer so I could accept it?